# How to access the DOM after a previous JQuery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, dom

I'm not too familiar with JQuery so please be patient.

Essentially, I have two hyperlinks on a view that runs some JQuery script:

```
     <a href='#' class="deleteCustomer">Delete</a></td>
       .
       .
     <a href="#" class="undoCustomer">Undo</a>
```

So, each of these links access different parts of the same .js file. My "Delete" does some processing which does a soft delete in the database.  The DOM loads and this works fine. I'm using firebug and, when I insert a console.log in .js I can see the id of the Customer I want to delete and the rest is straight forward.

```
$(container).find('a.deleteCustomer:first').click(function(e) {
            console.log("CustomerId " + $(container).find('input[name=Customer_CustomerId]:first').val());
```

My "Undo", however, accesses the same .js on a different line and console.log in the 'undo' part of .js reveals that it's not being hit.

```
$(container).find('a.undoCustomer').click(function(e) {
    console.log("CustomerId " + $(container).find('input[name=Customer_CustomerId]:first').val());
```

So, it appears that the DOM is not ready (?).  If this is the case, how do I fix this?  Do I have to reload the DOM manually?  If so, how?

P.S. When I click 'Undo' first nothing seems to happen i.e. I don't get any console.logs in FireBug.  However, if I refresh the browser, it runs as expected i.e. the undo jquery about executes.

Comment: Check the log/console and make sure there are no errors that prevent the snippet of code from running (and thus attaching to the event). The DOM is *live* and it never needs to be "reloaded" as such (changes after a manipulation are directly observable). "DOM ready" refers to the initial DOM creation when it is created from the HTML markup (and it is important to wait for this, but if it was the culprit then the first binding would likely not work).

Comment: is html being loaded after you set up click handler? If so need to delgate handler to part of DOM that is present on page load. Seems like a very abstract way to remove something by triggering a click

Comment: There was something I should have added to my post.  The first time I click 'Undo' nothing happens - that is to say, there's no console.log written to Firebug.  When I refresh and click undo, the event fires and the undo section of my JQuery runs.

Answer (score 0):

Without the full code, it is difficult to tell. From your post, title and comments, I see two possible causes.

First, you might be running your code before the DOM is fully ready, then try to wrap all your javascript initialization script in:

```
$(function() {
   ... // your code here
});
```

Second, are you deleting the "input" when you click on delete? If this is the case, it would be normal that "find" does not recover it. The solution to have an undo in such case would be to hide the "input" and show it back when clicking "undo".